# Can I see the number of PCI slots with a command?

Tags: pci

I would like to see how many PCI slots I have in a server and how many of them are in use. Is this possible with just some Linux commands? (lspci doesn't seem to provide the exact information I need.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

May be you can use:

```
dmidecode -t 9
```

For getting number of slots:

```
dmidecode -t 9 | grep "System Slot Information" | wc -l
```

For getting count of available:

```
dmidecode -t 9 | grep -A3 "System Slot Information" | grep -c -B1 "Available"
```

More info [dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode).

Comment: This will get you just the slots which on second thought seems like what you actually wanted.

Comment: I think this is what OP needs.

Comment: I agree, I offered an alternative but also gave you a +1! Never used `dmidecode` time to go read about it!

Comment: I would suggest `-t slot` instead of numeric identifier to make it easier to understand but otherwise, great answer!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT - What might be better for you is `sudo lspci | grep PCI`**

I would recommend `sudo lspci` as this will tell you every port as well as when is plugged into them. Otherwise it will just list the port and something generic.

lspci man page excerpt:

> lspci is a utility for displaying information about PCI buses in the
>   system and devices connected to them.

Keep in mind that this will list every interface on the bus not just what most would think of as traditional pci slots...